# Different opcode for mov instruction than expected in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, fasm, mov

Let's say I have a very simple instruction `mov eax,12345h`. I assembled it using fasm and generated a bin file. When i checked the opcode of above instruction using hex editor it gave `66 B8 45 23 01 00` as the equivalent hex code. Now from what I have [studied](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2016/fall/cs301/lecture/09_28_machinecode.html), I was expecting the first byte to be `0xb8` to represent the "load a 32-bit constant into eax" instruction and rest four bytes to be same as above. The aritcle that I mentioned also states that the same `0xb8` instruction that loads a 32-bit constant into eax can be used with a `0x66` prefix to load a 16-bit constant but clearly I am not loading a 16 bit constant in my program. Still the resulting opcode in my case starts with `66` as the first byte. Now I am not able to understand from where this `66` came ? Is there any different behavior in case of fasm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `66h` prefix byte is the Operand Size prefix. When used in 32 bit code, it specifies a 16 bit operand size, and when used in 16 bit code it specifies a 32 bit operand.

So you're assembling 16 bit x86 code. When loading a 32 bit value into a 32 bit register, the operand size prefix is required.